# Adjust the text position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a bar chart with error bar on it. In short, the blue bar is the mean and the red error bar is the standard deviation. However, some mean values are negative while some are positive, so it would be hard to see some text clearly when I write the following code.

```
for i in range(len(col_name)):
    plt.text(col_name[i], mean[i]+0.03, round(std[i],3), fontsize = 8, color='black')
```

which shows (so the third bar is hard to see the value)
[image]

Are there any ways to move the text position automatically?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since your values appear to be centered around zero, I would add a line before the text command saying `y_pos = mean[i]+0.03 if mean[i] > 0 else mean[i]-0.03`.

Comment: That's an easy way to do it! Thanks a lot